# REST request in SOAP UI

Tags: rest, soapui

I am trying to make a REST POST request in SoapUI.. The XML contract  for the same is

```
<Login>
<Email>admin</Email>
<Password>123456</Password>
</Login>
```

I have passed the values as follows in the REST request in SoapUI to the URL http://localhost:8080/SalesPropeller/rest/api/restLogin

```
Name     Value   Style   level
Email    admin   Query  Resource
Password 123456  Query  Resource
```

How do I pass the parameters in SoapUI?

Should the root tag name be included?If yes, How?

Comment: Your question is bit unclear.. DO you want to pass value programmatically or using some tool..??

Comment: @Krithika Ramkumar, would like to see the documentation to see if this helps - http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

It is based on how your backend expects the payload. 
From XML Contract, Your request payload should be like this

```
<Login>
<Email>admin</Email>
<Password>123456</Password>
</Login>
```

If you want to add properties, to send variables as field values

```
<Login>
<Email>${propertyName}</Email>
<Password>${propertyName}</Password>
</Login>
```

For creating properties, refer http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/working-with-properties.html